# Ethernet Splitter Issue

Tags: ethernet

I made a cable to split ethernet (small project I'm working on). I have a CAT 6 cable wired to an RJ45 male as follows

WO O WG B WB G WBr Br

On the other end I have female connectors. Connector 1 is wired as follows

1 - WO 2 - O 3 - WG 6 - G

Connector 2

1 - WB 2 - B 3 - WBr 6 - Br

The cable coming from connector 1 delivers a connection, however connector 2 does not. Any insight?

//Edit please stop advising me not to use this. I'm not using this for home networking or any solution to something. I'm working on an experiment and messing with things for knowledge and fun. Thanks

Comment: @grawity again, it's just something I'm playing around with for fun. I have many switches for this reason. Waste of a good cat6? I have about 10000 feet of it sitting in my house.

Comment: There really is no such thing as an ethernet splitter. The cabling standard does not allow you to do this, requiring four pairs for one connection. What you have done is to split off the "unused" pairs for 10BASE-T or 100BASE-TX, or you have messed up 1000BASE-T. Those "unused" pairs may actually be used for PoE, depending on what is connected to the other end. The frequencies of ethernet communications are such that simple electrical conductivity is insufficient. That are many parameters which must be met for successful ethernet communication.

Comment: Yes, well, things tend to happen like this. 2006: "It's just until we install a proper switch next month – I did it at home and it worked fine." 2016: "What were they thinking. /o\"

Comment: Please don't do this @Chris

Comment: @grawity I have switches installed. It's not for use in terms of home networking. I'm putting something together just for fun it was more of an experiment

Comment: @mikebabcock Why not?

Comment: @Chris you can use the wires for anything you want as wires, I've certainly used them for serial, but its not CAT6 once you've changed the twist distance or the pairs any more.  That label has a meaning.  The pairs used for data are not duplicated, so all you've done is wire a cable the wrong way (rather than 'split' it).  IEEE has good documentation if you intend to do Ethernet with your experiments.

Comment: It's working fine as it was intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike phone lines, there is nothing in the 10/100BASE-T specs that would allow two independent connections over the same Ethernet port. Instead, you always have one RX pair, one TX pair, and two *unused* pairs. So if the port at end A is in 10/100 Mbit mode, the other two pairs will just remain disconnected.

(Gigabit Ethernet, meanwhile, requires all four pairs, and many older devices don't actually check them before negotiation – so you are likely to end up with devices negotiating 1000BASE-T and being unable to use it. Recent Ethernet adapters are smarter, though.)

If you insist on it, you'll have to split *both* ends identically – with two jacks on each end, each wired with pairs 1/2 and 3/6.

Comment: Identically meaning same pins on both end jacks correct?

Comment: Identically meaning all of them with pairs 1/2 and 3/6 only.

Answer (score 1):

Gigabit Ethernet requires the use of all four pairs.  Perhaps earlier Ethernet standards allowed you to do this, but you won't be able to use Gigabit in this setup.  Additionally, I don't think you're going to be able to have a very long cable strand.  Each twisted pair is supposed to cancel out EM sources from adjacent cables and other EM sources.  I'd be concerned about the two sets of signals interfering with each other. EDIT: Nope, I was wrong.  The pairs each have slightly different twist rates specifically so that they don't interfere with each other.

Remember to put a label on the hacked cable so that you don't use it for something standard by mistake.

Comment: I've already got it from @grawity's answer, thank you though. And it'll be obvious which Frankenstein looking cable it is, thanks for the heads up though.